Too many query rows: 50001 error in flow with single record found in separate query
So the problem is that in flow i get an error: Error Occurred: Too many query rows: 50001
I get it from GetRecord in Flow, yet when I do same query with inspector I do get single record.
Have anyone had similar issue? Is there any other solution then sending request to support? We all know how helpful they are ...



Edit 1:
After some more testing I foudn out that even if I will select Products with out TimeSheetEntry in related Pricebook I still get the same issue. It is like getRecord is throwing it before conditions are checked.

PricebookId in your flow screenshot vs query don't look the same. You're sure you really run like for like? In same org? Does this flow waste lots of query rows before hitting this node? it might be just last thing that breaks it but the problem is earlier...
